# MediaWiki widgets aren't displaying

Tags: widget, mediawiki

I work on an internal company wiki (so I can't provide any links), but I'll illustrate my problem as best as I can.

**Problem:** When I insert the wiki syntax to display a widget, it produces this instead:

> Allows wiki administrators to add free-form widgets to the wiki by editing pages within the Widget namespace. Community-contributed widgets can be found on [MediaWikiWidgets.org](http://MediaWikiWidgets.org)

Widgets I'm using:

- [Google Spreadsheet](http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Widget%3aGoogle_Spreadsheet)
- [Google Calendar](http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Widget%3aGoogle_Calendar)
- [Google Document](http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Widget%3aGoogle_Document)

I've followed all of the instructions as described on those three pages. I've also installed the [widget extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWidgets) (1.0) as needed. **Note** that when viewing the "Special:Version" mediawiki page, it displays this as the description for the widget:

> Allows wiki administrators to add free-form widgets to the wiki by editing pages within the Widget namespace. Community-contributed widgets can be found on [MediaWikiWidgets.org](http://MediaWikiWidgets.org)

I'm in the process of confirming the [folder permissions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWidgets#Folder_permissions) currently used by our server, to ensure they match those as required by the widget extension, though I assume the permissions are correct. The PHP and MySQL versions being used are adequate for both MediaWiki and the Widget extension.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to git init the submodule?

cd Widgets
git submodule init
git submodule update